# Two same type of dataframes perform differently in a function

Tags: r

Below is my data

```
set.seed(100)
toydata <- data.frame(A = sample(1:50,50,replace = T),
                      B = sample(1:50,50,replace = T),
                      C = sample(1:50,50,replace = T)

)
```

Below is my swapping function

```
derangement <- function(x){
  if(max(table(x)) > length(x)/2) return(NA)
  while(TRUE){
    y <- sample(x)
    if(all(y != x)) return(y)
  }
}

swapFun <- function(x, n = 10){
  inx <- which(x < n)
  y <- derangement(x[inx])
  if(length(y) == 1) return(NA) 
  x[inx] <- y
  x
}
```

In the first case,I get the new data `toy` by swapping the entire dataframe. The code is below:

```
toydata<-as.matrix(toydata)
toy<-swapFun(toydata)
toy<-as.data.frame(toy)
```

In the second case, I get the new data `toy` by swapping each column respectively. Below is the code:

```
toydata<-as.data.frame(toydata)
toy2 <- toydata    # Work with a copy
toy2[] <- lapply(toydata, swapFun)
toy<-toy2
```

Below is the function that can output the difference of contigency table after swapping.

```
# the function to compare contingency tables
f = function(x,y){
  table1<-table(toydata[,x],toydata[,y])
  table2<-table(toy[,x],toy[,y])
  sum(abs(table1-table2))
}

# vectorise your function
f = Vectorize(f)


combn(x=names(toydata),
      y=names(toydata), 2) %>%# create all combinations of your column names
      t() %>%                                  # transpose
      data.frame(., stringsAsFactors = F) %>%  # save as dataframe
      filter(X1 != X2) %>%                     # exclude pairs of same 
                                           # column
      mutate(SumAbs = f(X1,X2))                # apply function
```

In the second case, this `mutate` function works.

But in the first case, this `mutate`function does not work. It says:

```
+   filter(X1 != X2) %>%                     # exclude pairs of same column
+   mutate(SumAbs = f(X1,X2))                # apply function
Error in combn(x = names(toydata), y = names(toydata), 2) : n < m
```

However in the two cases, the `toy` data are all dataframes with the same dimension, the same row names and the same column names. I feel confused.

How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: In the first case you do `toydata<-as.matrix(toydata)` which removes the names, as it's not a data frame any more. So the code later can't find any names in `toydata`. You can check by running `toydata<-as.matrix(toydata);
names(toydata)` and then `toydata<-as.data.frame(toydata);
names(toydata)`

Comment: After I add `toydata<-as.data.frame(toydata)` to rename it at the end of the first case, it still does not work......

Comment: Hi, after doing `toydata<-as.matrix(toydata)`  and  `names(toydata)` ,  I will get the right names by `toydata<-as.data.frame(toydata)` and `names(toydata)`  again. so It means I can get the original dataframe after these steps. But why does the code not work?

Comment: It's a different error now. The tables you produce (table1 and table2) don't have the same dimensions for some reason.

Comment: Yes, You are right! Thanks.